# 2 column layout issue - stacking and floating

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, multiple-columns

Probably a fairly basic solution to this, but I can't seem to figure it out... have set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/AxKq8/1/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="box-1" class="box">
</div>
<div id="box-2" class="box">
</div>
<div id="box-3" class="box">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
width: 100%;
}

.box {
width: 50%;
}

#box-1 {
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
}

#box-2 {
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}

#box-3 {
height: 300px;
float:right;
background-color: green;
position: relative;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

I have 3 divs. What I'd like to do is have the top of the green div align with the top of the blue div.

As you can see I tried floating the first two divs left, and the third div right. That didn't work, so tried a relative positioning. Also tried using clear aswell, but it's eluding me!

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positioned the third `div` `absolute` with `top:0`

```
#box-3 {
    height: 300px;
    float:right;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px; 
  }
```

Working CODE[:JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/AxKq8/7/)

Comment: Hey thanks @Shadow! This answer worked best for me due to this being applied to Wordpress widgets... and I had limited control over changing the HTML for the divs as the other answers suggested.

Comment: Voting is the arrows at the top left yeah? I did that... let me know if I need to do something else. Thanks!

Comment: @jonharris.photography:Thanks Man!!

Answer (score 2):

You can put the blue and red box in a container, and then a green box in another container. Float the two containers rather than the boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/AxKq8/9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="box-1" class="box">
        </div>
        <div id="box-2" class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="box-3" class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    float: left;
    width: 50%
}

#box-1 {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#box-2 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#box-3 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks @anita! Perfect solution, although had to go with another answer - I forgot to mention in my original question that I am dealing with Wordpress widgets, so I have limited control in this situation over how the page puts togethor the HTML. But thanks - will remember this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/AxKq8/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box-group box">
        <div id="box-1" class="box2"></div>
        <div id="box-2" class="box2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-group box">
        <div id="box-3" class="box2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{ width: 100%; }
.box { width: 50%; }
.box2 { width: 100%; }
.box-group { float: left; }
#box-1 { height: 200px; background-color: blue; }
#box-2 { height: 100px; background-color: red; }
#box-3 { height: 300px; background-color: green; }
```

I created columns with the `.box-group` class, I grouped the first two items into the first column div so the stacking and floating will appear properly.

Comment: Hey Thanks @JRulle! Perfect solution, although had to go with another answer - I forgot to mention in my original question that I am dealing with Wordpress widgets, so I have limited control in this situation over how the page puts togethor the HTML. But thanks - will remember this for the future!